# Keeping certain text and discarding the rest from some elements using selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml

From the below html elements how can i choose to keep the text `hi there!!` and discard the other text `Cat` using css selector? Moreover, using `.text` or `.text.strip()` I don't get results but when I use `.text_content()` i get the text.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

html="""
<div id="item_type" data-attribute="item_type" class="ms-crm-Inline" aria-describe="item_type_c">
    <div>
        <label for="item_type_outer" id="Type_outer">
            <div class="NotVisible">Cat</div>
        Hi there!!
            <div class="GradientMask"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
"""
root = fromstring(html)
for item in root.cssselect("#Type_outer"):
    print(item.text)  # doesn't work
    print(item.text.strip()) # doesn't work
    print(item.text_content()) # working one
```

Result:

```
Cat 
Hi there!!
```

However, the result I wanna get is only `hi there!!` and for that what i tried is:

```
root.cssselect("#Type_outer:not(.NotVisible)") #it doesn't work either
```

And once again the questions:

1. Why `.text_content()` is working but `.text` or `.text.strip()` is not?
2. How can i get only `hi there!!` using css selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lxml tree model, the text you want to get is in the `tail` of the `div` with class "NotVisible" :

```
>>> root = fromstring(html)
>>> for item in root.cssselect("#Type_outer > div.NotVisible"):
...     print(item.tail.strip())
...
Hi there!!
```

So to answer the first question, only text node that is not preceded by element is in the parent's `text` property. Text node that has preceding sibling element, like the one in this question, will be in the `tail` property of that element.

Another way to get the text "Hi there!!" is by querying non-empty text node that is direct child of the `label`. Query of such level of detail can be done using XPath expression :

```
for item in root.cssselect("#Type_outer"):
    print(item.xpath("text()[normalize-space()]")[0].strip())
```

Comment: No way!!! You are so helpful. One last thing: can you tell me why `root.cssselect("#Type_outer:not(.NotVisible)")` it failed? Forgive my ignorance. Thanks again.

Comment: That expression selects *element with id "Type_outer" that doesn't have class  "NotVisible"*, so in this case, it basically returns the same element as simply `#Type_outer` since the label with that id also doesn't have class "NotVisible"